# Display wordpress comments in random order

Tags: wordpress

How can I display the comments on wordpress posts/pages in a random order?
Right now the only option is to have them displayed by new or old.

Basically on each page load, the comments should be shuffled so they appear in a random order

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter onto the comments array - Putting this in your functions.php file should do the trick.

```
function shuffle_comments( $comments , $post_id ) {
    return shuffle( $comments );
}

add_filter( 'comments_array' , 'shuffle_comments', 10, 2);
```

If you don't know much about  filters, essentially you can add them to parts of Wordpress to change data before it's displayed. This example is actually referenced in the [comments_array filter reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/comments_array).

Comment: I've just put this in functions.php and it breaks the site. I've added it in a php snippet and it does nothing.

Comment: Oops - there was a syntax error (closing php tag was present). I have removed that now.

Comment: I've added the updated code and it's no change, it doesn't shuffle the comments. Is it supose to work on pages as well, or only on posts? I'm asking because I have comments only on pages.

Answer (score 0):

When the array of comments/posts has been grabbed, use PHP's Shuffle function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php to shuffle the order around before the comments/posts are displayed. Each page load the comments/posts will be shuffled